# Camera intent not working on Panasonic toughbook fz-a2

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an app that was up till now used exclusively on Samsung devices. Now the app needs to run on a Panasonic tough pad FZ-A2. Everything works except for the camera intent. When the button is pressed the camera successfully launches, but after taking an image instead of saving the image it displays the following error "There was a problem saving your photo or video". the code I used to call the camera intent is as follows

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

// generates a new unique name base on the current date and time
String imageFileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SS", Locale.US).format(new Date());
imageFileName = imageFileName.replace(":", "-");
imageFileName = imageFileName.replace(" ", "_");
// capturedImage is used to keep track of where the image is saved to retrieve after intent is done.
capturedImage = new File(pictureDirectoryPath + imageFileName + ".jpg");
// makes it so the intent saves the image to a specific location
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(capturedImage));
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_INTENT);
```

pictureDirectoryPath is a variable initialized in onCreate with the following line

```
pictureDirectoryPath = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + dirName + File.separator;
```

The only thing i can think of is that maybe

```
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

doesn't work properly on this device. But if that is the case i don't know what i should use instead.

Comment: Did you add the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest?

Comment: Have you used the device's camera directly by hand first? Otherwise, it may not have runtime permissions for external storage yet.

Comment: What is the target SDK if it is greater than 22 you will have to also implement runtime permissions.

Comment: @Seishin yes i did. i also added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as well

Comment: @CommonsWare i tried using the standalone camera app on it and that worked just fine. it is only when i launch it from the button inside the app that is fails.

Comment: Hmmm... if the camera app can save to external storage, it should be OK with what you have. You could try using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` instead of `getExternalFilesDir()` and see if you have better luck, though I would be surprised. More likely, there's a bug in this device's camera app, as `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` seems to not get tested very much by camera app developers. :-(